# Best way to create a Union type for ImmutablePairs in Java

Tags: java, sum-type

In a Java program that I need to enhance I  have a data structure

```
List<ImmutablePair<Integer, String>> params;
```

using `ImmutablePair` from `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple`.

Going forward the String parameter needs to be able to hold *either* a `String` or a `Double`. For this I would like to create something like a union or Sum type of the two basic types.

How do I define this in Java for a list of `ImmutablePair`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear what your question has to do with `ImmutablePair`.

I would just do something like this:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface StringOrDouble {
    <T> T get(Function<String,T> stringFunc, Function<Double,T> doubleFunc);

    class StringVersion implements StringOrDouble {
        private final String string;

        public StringVersion(String string) {
            this.string = string;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T get(Function<String, T> stringFunc, Function<Double, T> doubleFunc) {
            return stringFunc.apply(string);
        }
    }

    class DoubleVersion implements StringOrDouble {
        private final Double doubleValue;

        public DoubleVersion(Double doubleValue) {
            this.doubleValue = doubleValue;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T get(Function<String, T> stringFunc, Function<Double, T> doubleFunc) {
            return doubleFunc.apply(doubleValue);
        }
    }

    static StringOrDouble ofString(String string) {
        return new StringVersion(string);
    }
    static StringOrDouble ofDouble(Double doubleValue) {
        return new DoubleVersion(doubleValue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringOrDouble[] vs = {ofString("hello"),ofDouble(101.0)};
        for (StringOrDouble v : vs) {
            System.out.println(v.get(String::toUpperCase, Double::toHexString));
        }
    }
}
```

And then use:

```
List<ImmutablePair<Integer, StringOrDouble>> params;
```

Or a generic version:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface Union<A, B> {

    <T> T get(Function<A, T> aFunc, Function<B, T> bFunc);

    class AVersion<A, B> implements Union<A, B> {
        private final A a;

        public AVersion(A a) {
            this.a = a;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T get(Function<A, T> aFunc, Function<B, T> bFunc) {
            return aFunc.apply(a);
        }
    }

    class BVersion<A, B> implements Union<A, B> {
        private final B b;

        public BVersion(B b) {
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public <T> T get(Function<A, T> aFunc, Function<B, T> bFunc) {
            return bFunc.apply(b);
        }
    }

    static <A, B> Union<A, B> ofA(A a) {
        return new AVersion<>(a);
    }

    static <A, B> Union<A, B> ofB(B b) {
        return new BVersion<>(b);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Union<String, Double>> vs = List.of(ofA("hello"), ofB(101.0));
        for (Union<String, Double> v : vs) {
            System.out.println(v.get(String::toUpperCase, Double::toHexString));
        }
    }
}
```

We can also add a method to `Union`:

```
    default void use(Consumer<A> aConsumer, Consumer<B> bConsumer) {
        get(a -> {aConsumer.accept(a); return null;}, b -> {bConsumer.accept(b); return null;});
    }
```

Which allows us to pass void methods, so if we have a bean like:

```
class Foo {
        private String s;
        private double d;

        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public double getD() {
            return d;
        }

        public void setD(double d) {
            this.d = d;
        }
    }
```

we can do:

```
        Union<String, Double> u = ofA("a string");
        Foo f = new Foo();
        u.use(f::setS, f::setD);
```

And the appropriate setter will be called.

Comment: Thanks. Makes Sense. -- But it is _a lot_ of code. Is there a standard way (or a library) to do this?

Comment: Also (and excuse my possibly obvious question), how can I check on `get` which type a `DoubleOrString` variable actually  contains?

Comment: The way I have written it you don't check. Feel free to edit your question and explain your requirements.

Comment: Yes, I see all "communication" with the object is done via the `get` method... I will try to add a `multiSet` method wheer depending on the actual type the correct setter in another object is called. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Not completely sure if I read the question correctly, but a very easy way to implement a union type would be:

```
public class Union<A, B> {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;

    private Union(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public boolean isA() {
        return a != null;
    }

    public boolean isB() {
        return b != null;
    }

    public A getA() {
        if(isA()) {
            return a;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public B getB() {
        if(isB()) {
            return b;
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    public static <A, B> Union<A, B> ofA(A a) {
        return new Union<A, B>(Objects.requireNonNull(a), null);
    }

    public static <A, B> Union<A, B> ofB(B b) {
        return new Union<A, B>(null, Objects.requireNonNull(b));
    }
}
```

If you don't use generics you could also drop the static `of` methods and simply use two different constructors but with generics that won't work because of the type erasure.

You'd call is like this:

```
Union<String, Double> union = Union.ofA("bla");
if(union.isA()) {
    System.out.println(union.getA());
}
if(union.isB()) {
    System.out.println(union.getB());
}
```

Comment: Despite its name, what your answer has implemented is not a union but rather the *opposite*: [unions are sum types, but your implementation is a product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Comment: Actually I hadn’t noticed that you had made the constructor private. Given the current interface this *is* a sum type, albeit one with an inefficient implementation and a convoluted interface.

Comment: I agree, this is not ideal. Some languages have built-in union types but Java does not. So I had to use a workaround. I know I always have a field that is null which is not too pretty but it's still better than simply storing one ```Object``` and then use a cast ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this implementation. Looks interesting too. I guess the interface approach from the answer is a bit closer to a real Sum type.